# Как убрать стрелочку возле выбора месяца в QCalendarWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qss, qcalendarwidget

Есть код для внешнего вида календаря, сделанного в *PyQt5*.

Я хочу убрать стрелочку возле выбора месяца, однако не знаю как это сделать. Помогите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код:

```
Calendar_StyleSheet =   '''
/* Верхняя область */
#qt_calendar_navigationbar {
    background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212);
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
}

/* Кнопка последнего месяца и кнопка следующего месяца */
#qt_calendar_prevmonth, #qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    border: none;                     /* убрать границу */
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: white;
    min-width: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;            /* выглядит как эллипс */
    font-weight: bold;              /* шрифт полужирный */
    qproperty-icon: none;    
    background-color: transparent; /* Цвет фона прозрачный */
}

#qt_calendar_prevmonth {
    qproperty-text: "<";         /* Изменить текст кнопки  */
}
#qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    qproperty-text: ">";
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:hover, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:pressed, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/*  год, месяц                                                */
#qt_calendar_yearbutton, #qt_calendar_monthbutton {
    color: white;
    margin: -1px;
    min-width: -1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 212, 100)
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:hover, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:pressed, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/* Поле ввода года */
#qt_calendar_yearedit {
    min-width: 85px;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;         /* Сделать фон окна ввода прозрачным */
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::up-button {   /* Кнопка вверх */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: right;      
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::down-button { /* Кнопка вниз */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: left;       
}

/* меню выбора месяца */
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu {
     background-color: white;
}

CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item {
    padding: 10px;
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item_selected_enabled {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    selection-color: rgb(45, 86, 100);
    selection-background-color: rgb(205, 217, 226);
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_menu-indicator {
    subcontrol-position: right center;                
}

/* ниже календарной формы */
#qt_calendar_calendarview {
    outline: 0px;                                 /* Удалить выделенную пунктирную рамку */
    selection-background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212); 
}
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вы поломали все стили, которые начинаются с **`CalendarWidget`** ??

Исправьте все и добавьте строку

```
image: none;    /* Удалите маленькую стрелку под выбором месяца !!! */
```

---

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCharFormat, QBrush, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QCalendarWidget


class CalendarWidget(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CalendarWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # Вертикальный заголовок. 
        self.setVerticalHeaderFormat(self.NoVerticalHeader)

        # Изменить цвета субботы и воскресенья
        fmtGreen = QTextCharFormat()
        fmtGreen.setForeground(QBrush(Qt.green))
        self.setWeekdayTextFormat(Qt.Saturday, fmtGreen)
        fmtOrange = QTextCharFormat()
        fmtOrange.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(252, 140, 28)))
        self.setWeekdayTextFormat(Qt.Sunday, fmtOrange)


Calendar_StyleSheet =   '''
/* Верхняя область */
#qt_calendar_navigationbar {
    background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212);
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
}

/* Кнопка последнего месяца и кнопка следующего месяца */
#qt_calendar_prevmonth, #qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    border: none;                     /* убрать границу */
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: white;
    min-width: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;            /* выглядит как эллипс */
    font-weight: bold;              /* шрифт полужирный */
    qproperty-icon: none;    
    background-color: transparent; /* Цвет фона прозрачный */
}

#qt_calendar_prevmonth {
    qproperty-text: "<";         /* Изменить текст кнопки  */
}
#qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    qproperty-text: ">";
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:hover, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:pressed, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/*  год, месяц                                                */
#qt_calendar_yearbutton, #qt_calendar_monthbutton {
    color: white;
    margin: -1px;
    min-width: -1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 212, 100)
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:hover, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:pressed, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/* Поле ввода года */
#qt_calendar_yearedit {
    min-width: 85px;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;         /* Сделать фон окна ввода прозрачным */
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::up-button {   /* Кнопка вверх */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: right;      
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::down-button { /* Кнопка вниз */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: left;       
}

/* меню выбора месяца 
              ?           ?             ????????????????????????????????
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu {      зачем вы наставили подчеркивание ? */
CalendarWidget QToolButton QMenu {
     background-color: white;
}
/*            ?           ?     ??
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item { */
CalendarWidget QToolButton QMenu::item {
    padding: 10px;
}
/*            ?           ?     ??   ?        ?
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item_selected_enabled {  */
CalendarWidget QToolButton QMenu::item:selected:enabled {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    selection-color: rgb(45, 86, 100);
    selection-background-color: rgb(205, 217, 226);
}
/*            ?           ??   
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_menu-indicator {               */
CalendarWidget QToolButton::menu-indicator {
    image: none;       /* Удалите маленькую стрелку под выбором месяца !!! */
    subcontrol-position: right center;                
}

/* ниже календарной формы */
#qt_calendar_calendarview {
    outline: 0px;                                 /* Удалить выделенную пунктирную рамку */
    selection-background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212); 
}
'''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Calendar_StyleSheet)
    w = CalendarWidget()
    w.resize(800, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]